# What's the difference between Imaginary Thinking and Imaginal Thinking?

Tags: thought

What's the difference between Imaginary Thinking and Imaginal Thinking?

I hear somebody say the Imaginary Thinking is belong Imaginal Thinking, is it true?

please give me a detail explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imaginary thinking is wishful thinking. About times and places you like to be. How would it be like in a faraway place? How would it be living in the future or in the past?
Imaginary thinking is thinking about imaginary places too. Thinking about fantasy lands in fantasy times. Or about what you are going to write or paint, and as such it's a part of creative thinking.
And then there is imaginary thinking about what you like to do, how music sounds like, how will your friend be doing, how you gonna pay back, what the smell of a rose is like (though somewhat difficult), etc.
Imaginary thinking can be imagining the unimaginable, like atoms or sub-atomic particles. Or how the DNA in your cells is transported, what drives a person to do things, thinking about scientific stuff (a part of scientific thought), or thinking about a speech to be delivered.
It can be about a thinking that is imaginary. An imaginary thinking.

Imaginal thinking is *a way* of thinking (imaginary thinking is not). It is a thinking in a specified way, to achieve certain aims connected with this thinking. You can apply this thinking to imaginary thinking but I guess it will impart the process of the imaginary. The specific structure of this kind of thinking can be found in the lectures on the internet.